# React ts input resets to props value after rerender

Tags: reactjs

In React ts I have a modal container:

```
const DeployModal: React.FC<{ show: any, handleClose: any }> = ({ show, handleClose }) => {...}
```

And a MyInput component:

```
  const MyInput = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, { defaultValue: string }>(({ defaultValue }, ref) => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState(defaultValue)

    const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      const newValue = event.target.value
        setValue(newValue);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <ModalInput ref={ref} onChange={handleChange} value={value} />
      </div>
    );
  })
```

In the DeployModal parent component, I render:

```
<div>{inputError}</div>
<MyInput ref={inputRef} defaultValue='21000000'></MyInput>
<div onClick={validateData}>Validate data</div>
```

When I run the `validateData` function I check:

With

```
 const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
 const [inputError, setInputError] = useState("")

  const validateData = () => {
    const inputVal = inputRef.current?.value;
    
    if(inputVal && inputVal == '') {
      setInputError("Can't be empty")
    } else {
      setInputError("")
    }
  }
```

When I press on Validate data, some strange behaviour happens. Every time a DeployModal re-render occurs (when `setInputError()` is being executed) the input switches back to its `defaultData` either immediately, or the next time a user clicks on validate data.

What is the issue?

Comment: Is there anything that is causing `DeployModal` to unmount? Because you may be accidentally destroying and recreating the component on every render cycle. This can happen so fast that it looks like it never left the DOM. This would cause the default mounting behavior to occur every time.